# Pandas - How adding new empty rows with index coming from a list of DateTimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I am sorry, I am kind of stuck.

I would like to use DateTimeIndex coming from a column in a dataframe, to create new rows in another dataframe.

These DateTimeIndex have to be used as indexes for the new rows.

So with following data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Start': [pd.Timestamp('1970-01-02 00:00:00'),pd.Timestamp('1970-03-02 00:00:00')], 'End': [pd.Timestamp('1970-01-02 00:10:00'), pd.Timestamp('1970-03-02 00:10:00')], 'Freq': [pd.Timedelta(5,'m'),pd.Timedelta(5,'m')]})
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start = x.Start, end = x.End, freq = x.Freq), axis=1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':[pd.Timestamp('1970-01-03 00:00:00')], 'Data':[4]}).set_index('Timestamp')
```

I get the inputs:

```
In [62]: df2.index
Out[62]: DatetimeIndex(['1970-01-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Timestamp', freq=None)

In[63]: df.to_list()
Out[21]: 
[DatetimeIndex(['1970-01-02 00:00:00', '1970-01-02 00:05:00',
                '1970-01-02 00:10:00'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='5T'),
 DatetimeIndex(['1970-03-02 00:00:00', '1970-03-02 00:05:00',
                '1970-03-02 00:10:00'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='5T')]
```

What I would like to get is a dataframe based on df2, with new rows, having as timestamps those coming from df.

```
df2_new
                    Data
Timestamp       
1970-01-03 00:00:00    4
1970-01-02 00:00:00
1970-01-02 00:05:00
1970-01-02 00:10:00
1970-03-02 00:00:00
1970-03-02 00:05:00
1970-03-02 00:10:00
```

I tried with following line, but I get an error:

```
df2.reindex(df2.index.to_list() + df.to_list())

TypeError: unhashable type: 'DatetimeIndex'
```

The example I give is simplified as df has a single row, but it could have several.

Please, do you have any idea how I could do?

Thanks in advance for your help!
Have a good evening,
Bests!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can define your 'time range' a little differently, but the key step is to use [`pd.Index.union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Start':[pd.Timestamp('1970-01-02 00:00:00')], 
                   'End':[pd.Timestamp('1970-01-02 00:10:00')], 
                   'Freq':[pd.Timedelta(5,'m')]})
timerange = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.date_range(start = x.Start, 
                                                       end = x.End, 
                                                       freq = x.Freq)), 
                     axis=1).stack()[0]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':[pd.Timestamp('1970-01-03 00:00:00')], 
                    'Data':[4]}).set_index('Timestamp')

df2 = df2.reindex(df2.index.union(timerange))
df2
```

Output:

```
                     Data
1970-01-02 00:00:00   NaN
1970-01-02 00:05:00   NaN
1970-01-02 00:10:00   NaN
1970-01-03 00:00:00   4.0
```

Comment: Hello Scott, thanks a lot for this answer. Alas, df can have several rows. Let's consider a 2nd row then:

df = pd.DataFrame({'Start': [pd.Timestamp('1970-01-02 00:00:00'),pd.Timestamp('1970-03-02 00:00:00')],  'End': [pd.Timestamp('1970-01-02 00:10:00'), pd.Timestamp('1970-03-02 00:10:00')], 'Freq': [pd.Timedelta(5,'m'),pd.Timedelta(5,'m')]})


Then, I tried you code, but iterating over timerange, but it did not work:

for i in timerange.stack():
    df2 = df2.reindex(df2.index.union(i))


I get following error:

TypeError: Input must be Index or array-like

Comment: You time range records in df overlap?

Comment: However, you are selecting each timerange individually, you need to wrap in [] to make it a list.   Like this `for i in timerange:`   `df2 = df2.reindex(df2.index.union([i]))`

Comment: Scott, this is awesome! I wrapped it in [] as suggested, and it works like a charm! Thanks (I have modified my inputs above to reflect a 2nd line in df and what I want the result to be. You understood correctly, terrific! Thanks!